# Kafka consumer retry and recover

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I want to retry thrice whenever I encounter `DataAccessResourceFailureException`. However when the below code is encountered, it goes to recover immediately through I sent max attempts to 3.

**Listener Config**

```
public void listen(@Payload Map<String, Object> conciseMap,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                   Acknowledgment ack) {

        try {
            //logic                 
        } catch (DataAccessResourceFailureException ex){
            logger.error(" error while parsing response {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
}
```

**Retry Configuration**

```
    static {
        retryableExceptions = new HashMap<>();
        retryableExceptions.put(DataAccessResourceFailureException.class, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new ConciseMessageDeserializer());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConcurrency(conncurrency);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
        factory.setRecoveryCallback(new RecoveryCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object recover(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
                logger.debug(" In recovery callback method !!");
                ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = (ConsumerRecord) context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_RECORD);
                Map conciseMap = (Map)record.value();
                publisher.sendMessage((String)conciseMap.get("messagePayload"));
                ((Acknowledgment)context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT)).acknowledge();
                return null;
            }
        });
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        return factory;
    }

/*
 * Retry template.
 */

protected RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
    SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxRetryAttempts, retryableExceptions);
    return policy;
}

protected BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy policy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    policy.setInitialInterval(initialRetryInterval);
    policy.setMultiplier(retryMultiplier);
    return policy;
}

protected RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
   RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
   template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
   template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy());
   return template;
}
```

**DEBUG Logs**

> 09:24:26.856
>   [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-L-1]
>   DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=1
>   09:24:26.856
>   [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-L-1]
>   DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry failed last attempt:
>   count=1 09:24:26.856
>   [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-L-1]
>   DEBUG c.c.c.tas.config.KafkaConsumerConfig -  In recovery callback
>   method !!

Comment: Can you share `retryTemplate()` contents, please?

Comment: You have strange static block about `retryableExceptions`, but your

Comment: You have suspicious static block for the `retryableExceptions`, but you don't show `RetryPolicy` definition on the matter.

Comment: @ArtemBilan added retry policy details

Comment: @PunterVicky sanity check - does the `catch DataAccessResourceFailureException` block get executed?

Comment: Hi Adam, yes it did get executed

Comment: I explicitly threw that exception

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.retry` to really see in logs what it retries and what not. And maybe we will have some info "Why?"

Comment: Sure @ArtemBilan , I will check it

Comment: There is `maxRetryAttempts`, but we don't know what is its value

Comment: Sorry , I didn't paste it here. It is set as 3.

Comment: @Value(value = "${tas.retry.maxAttempts:3}")
 private int maxRetryAttempts;

Comment: @ArtemBilan I printed the retrycount to make sure it is 3. I have also pasted the debug logs.

Comment: When I replaced DataAccessResourceFailureException.class to Exception.class in retryableExceptions map , I see 3 retries.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I replaced Exception again with DataAccessResourceFailureException in the retryableExceptions map. Now I see the exception being retried thrice! I am not sure what I was doing wrong :-) Thanks for your suggestion to add debug info , it was really helpful.